# Retornar a mesma Paginação apos um post no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Eu tenho uma paginação de clientes com um botão que ativa ou desativa um cliente dessa lista. Porem se eu estiver na Pag=4 (por exemplo), quando ativo ou Desativo o cliente eu volto para pagina inicial e perco a paginação onde eu estava.
E possível, realizar o post e retornar a mesma pagina?
Segue abaixo o código da Controladora:

```php
public function alterarStatus(Request $request) {

    if ($request->ativar) {
        $clientes = ClientesRepository::ativarCliente($request->id);
        return redirect()->route('admin.clientes')->with('success', 'Cliente ativado com sucesso');
    }
    $clientes = ClientesRepository::desativarCliente($request->id);
    return redirect()->route('admin.clientes')->with('success', 'Cliente desativado com sucesso');
}
```

A Rota 'admin.clientes' retornar o seguinte:

```php
public function clientes() {
    $email = null;
    $nome = null;
    $cidade = null;
    $estado = null;
    $quantidadePorPagina = 10;
    $clientes = ClientesRepository::clientesLista($quantidadePorPagina);
    return view('admin.clientes.clientes', compact('clientes', 'email', 'nome', 'cidade', 'estado'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara você pode usar estre próprio helper do Laravel, deve te ajudar, caso não ajude, estou pensando em armazenar em session a sua ultima url e retornar com ela.

> url()->previous()

Mas só se caso isso não te ajudar.

```
 public function alterarStatus(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->ativar) {
            $clientes = ClientesRepository::ativarCliente($request->id);
            return redirect()->to(url()->previous())->with('success', 'Cliente ativado com sucesso');
        }
        $clientes = ClientesRepository::desativarCliente($request->id);
        return  redirect()->to(url()->previous())->with('success', 'Cliente desativado com sucesso');
    }
```

Comment: Esse metodo funcionou, todavia acabei enviando no formulado o $_GET['page'] e retornando o mesmo na rota:

Comment: Perfeito. Muito bem!